# docker-compose up - set the environment variable for the containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I don't understand how `environment:` in `docker-compose.yml` works.

So if I have

```
environment:
  - MY_ENV_VAR
  - MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR
```

Now, how do I set them when calling `docker-compose up` ?

I tried with `export` before.

I tried with `-e KEY=VALUE`

But nothing seems to be working.

When I ssh to the container and check the `env`, I don't find `MY_ENV_VAR` or `MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue.

If your `yml` file have several services:

```
one:
  environment:
    - VAR_ONE
two:
  environment:
    - VAR_ONE
    - VAR_TWO
```

And you do

```
export VAR_ONE=1
export VAR_TWO=2
docker-compose up
```

And then `ssh` to `two`, you will **NOT** see `VAR_TWO` set.

If you change the `yml` to:

```
one:
  environment:
    - VAR_ONE
    - VAR_TWO
two:
  environment:
    - VAR_ONE
    - VAR_TWO
```

Notice that each service have the exact same env keys.

**Then it works !**

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a values in the yml file.

```
environment:
  - MY_ENV_VAR=foo
  - MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=bar
```

You can also use environment variable in the yml file.

```
 environment:
  - MY_ENV_VAR=${foo}
  - MY_SECOND_ENV_VAR=${bar}
```

Comment: Yeah I don't really want to do that. I want to be able to set it only when I spin up the cluster